# How to ensure controller is injected into directive for test?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine, smart-table

I'm using [Smart Table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/)  and trying to get some tests set up with Karma. I'm repeatedly getting the error `Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'stTable', required by directive 'removePag', can't be found!`. I don't get any errors when actually using the directive. It seems to me that Karma should be making smart-table available to the `tools` module, which is what I'm referring to in the spec, but no dice. How can I be sure `stTable` is available to `removePag` in testing?

In tools.js (including `expose` because I suspect it may be involved, as it is a directive linked to the top-level `st-table`):

```
angular.module('tools', ['smart-table'] );

angular
    .module('freeTools')
        .directive('expose', exposeTableState)
        .directive('removePag', removePag)

function exposeTableState(){
    return {
        require:'stTable',
            link:function(scope, element, attr, ctrl){
            scope.smartTableState=ctrl.tableState();
        }
    };
}

function removePag() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^stTable',
        template: '<a href="">View as a single page</a>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            return element.bind('click', function () {
                return scope.$apply(function () {
                    var tableState;
                    tableState = ctrl.tableState();
                    tableState.pagination.number = tableState.pagination.totalItemCount;
                    return ctrl.pipe();
                });
            });

        }
      };
}
```

In toolsSpec.js:

```
describe('tools', function () {
    var $compile,
    $rootScope;
    beforeEach(module('freeTools'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_){
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));

    it('Replaces the element with the appropriate content', function() {
        var element = $compile("<remove-pag></remove-pag>")($rootScope);
        $rootScope.$digest();
        expect(element.html()).toContain("View as a single page");
    });
}
```

In Karma.conf:

```
module.exports = function(config){
config.set({

basePath : '../../',

files : [
    'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    'bower_components/angular-smart-table/dist/smart-table.js',
    'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'assets/scripts/*.js',
    'assets/test/*.js'
],

autoWatch : true,

frameworks: ['jasmine-ajax', 'jasmine'],

browsers : ['Chrome'],

plugins : [
        'karma-chrome-launcher',
        'karma-firefox-launcher',
        'karma-jasmine-ajax',
        'karma-jasmine',
        ],
});
};
```

Simplified html:

```
<section ng-app="tools">
  <table st-table="data" st-safe-src="safe" expose>
    <div st-pagination>
      <remove-pag></remove-pag>
```

I realize the question is very similar to [Unit testing an AngularJS (Smart Table) directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541042/unit-testing-an-angularjs-smart-table-directive). Mimicking the way smart tables tests their own controllers didn't work, either, as suggested there. Anyway, `stTable` in the module's source code seems to be a directive, not a controller.

I've also tried wrapping the element with st-table in the test, like `$compile("<table st-table><remove-pag>...` with the same error.

I've looked at issues like [Controller Required By Directive Can't Be Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342698/controller-required-by-directive-cant-be-found), but I already have a shared parent, `tools`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, apparently, that the parent *must* be mocked. H/t to [Unit testing AngularJS child directive that requires parent directive](https://demisx.github.io/angularjs/unit-testing/2014/10/28/unit-testing-angular-child-directive-that-requires-parent.html) for the guidance on mocking.

```
it('Replaces the element with the appropriate content', function() {
    // This can be anything, even an empty object.
    var stTableControllerMock = {
        idk: function () {
            return 'something';
        }
    };

    // Create element with dummy parent
    var element = angular.element('<fake-parent><remove-pag></remove-pag></fake-parent>');

    // '$' + {nameOfMissingController} + 'Controller' = '$stTableController'
    element.data('$stTableController', stTableControllerMock);

    // Compile, find the element we're testing, and digest
    $compile(element)($rootScope.$new());
    element = element.find('remove-pag');
    $rootScope.$digest();

    // Test
    expect(element.html()).toContain("View as a single page");
});
```